# Not able to quit ember serve from terminal

Tags: macos, ember.js

> I can't get ctrl-C to work in mac Terminal when ember server is running.
>   If I type ctrl-C, the terminal just beeps at me. It seems like the
>   only way I can get out is with ctrl-Z, which leaves me with a stopped
>   process.

Again i have to do kill -9 pid to kill the process and again start the serve. Is there any command to quit the ember server ?

Comment: That looks quite strange. Do you have non-US keyboard layout? ;; Perhaps it will help that you can do kill -9 %1 ; to stop the first stopped process

Comment: Yes. I have non Us layout .. I am looking on to some command , which can kill the process instantly without kill -9

Comment: Hi Manikandan, can you stop other terminal processes with `ctrl-c`?

Comment: Yes , i can able to stop the other terminal processes with `ctrl+c`

Answer (score 0):

Control-C is the normal way to handle this, sounds like something is different on your machine ...